# Production of Angular2 project

Tags: angular

This is my first angular2 project production. 
I used this answer from this site.
2.4.x FINAL (TypeScript) with Angular CLI 1.0.0-beta.24

OneTime Setup

```
npm install -g angular-cli
```

`ng init` from projectFolder if it is an existing application
ng new projectFolder if it is an new application.

Bundling Steps

`ng build --prod --aot` (run in command line when directory is projectFolder)
flag prod bundle for production and flag aot enable the ahead-of-time compilation also known as offline compilation.

bundles are generated by default to projectFolder/dist/

Output

```
dist/main.[hash].bundle.js Your application bundled [ size: 13 KB for new Angular CLI application empty, ~3 KB compressed].
dist/vendor.[hash].bundle.js Your dependencies (@angular, RxJS...) bundled [ size: 437 KB for new Angular CLI application empty, 98 KB compressed].
dist/index.html entry point of your application.
dist/inline.js webpack loader
dist/style.[hash].bundle.css the style definitions
dist/assetsresources copied from projectFolder/src/assets
dist/*.[hash].bundle.map the SourceMaps corresponding to the previous files (it is not required for a production deployment)
```

But when i click dist/index.html i receive only loading ... and nothing else.
How Can i receive production version?

Comment: Are you double clicking on the index.html to open the project? :O

Comment: if i see loading..., it seems i do double click

Comment: any error in the chrome console?

Comment: double click??... :-(

Comment: i'm doing it in node.js command promt and there is no error messages

Comment: Are you running some kind of webserver to provide the other files in `dist/`? `index.html` just contains the bare bones, you need to be able to load the `.js` files to make the site work.

Comment: update the post with **errors** in the browser console

Answer (score 1):

You can't open/bootstrap the Angular2 project by double-clicking on the `index.html`. You need a back-end (nodejs, lite-server) or a deployment server (hosting sites like hostinger or apache tomcat servers).

The official documentation is [here](https://angular.io).

Comment: i want to load project locally as in documentation, that you had sent, but when i load 
http://localhost:4200
i saw only title "app works!"

Comment: @Alice which documentation are you following? I've linked 2. And what were you expecting to see?

Comment: ))) i would like to see result as i see when i'm doing npm start.
I'm folowwing first one (Getting started with Angular 2)

Comment: @Alice That is what you should see since it is only a tutorial. It only creates a component with `title = 'app works!';`. Here's the github link:https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#user-content-css-preprocessor-integration